# finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\arctan\left(\frac{2r}{1-r^2+r^4}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I want to find 
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\arctan\left(\frac{2r}{1-r^2+r^4}\right)$$
I already know that I need to split the expression $\frac{2r}{1-r^2+r^4}$ of the form $\frac{a_r+a_{r-1}}{1-a_ra_{r-1}}$ or $\frac{a_r-a_{r-1}}{1+a_ra_{r-1}}$ so that the main expression gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\arctan\left(\frac{a_r-a_{r-1}}{1+a_ra_{r-1}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}(\arctan(a_r)-\arctan(a_{r-1}))=\arctan(a_\infty)-\arctan(a_0)$$
But I am not able to split up that thing. Any hints on how to start?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint
$$a_r=r(r+1)$$
 $$\frac{a_r-a_{r-1}}{1+a_ra_{r-1}}=\frac{2r}{1-r^2+r^4}$$

Comment: Damned, too late :-)

Comment: anyways, thanks for that!

Comment: I meant *I* was too late by few minutes, to answer :-) Thanks to Sami of course!